# compare password with bCrypt returned false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I hash my password and save a user into db (using passport). Now I wrote an api (without passport) try to compare the password, it returned false although I key in the same string. Just curious why does it so? I doubt I know about how bCrypt works now. My code as below.

my model

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bCrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err){
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("model: " + isMatch)
            callback(null, isMatch);
        }
    });
}
```

controller 
http://pastebin.com/jCB4YUy0

Comment: I haven't used this before, but after some quick searching it looks like you're using it right. Have you tried outputting the candidatePassword variable to verify it's correct?

Comment: @EricDubé yes I do, it doesn't give me the same hash

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I need no to hash the password. The bCrypt module has that built in.